# Selenium Drag and Drop invokes exception

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

What is wrong with this? I keep getting an exception.
I actually have no idea.

> An exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetException' occurred in mscorlib.dll >but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Object does not match target type.

```
public IWebDriver _driver;

[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "column-a")]
private IWebElement _columnA;

[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "column-b")] 
private IWebElement _columnB;

var actions = new Actions(_driver);
actions.DragAndDrop(this._columnB, this._columnA);
actions.Build().Perform();
```

Comment: looks interesting, if you provide HTML page i will try in JAVA as i have hands in java. anyhow can you try once by changing private to public for IWebElement?

Comment: Can you share the `html`?

Comment: @muraliseleniumtrainer http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/drag_and_drop,

Comment: It is on the Perform(); the exception happens